# Content wiped out when updating with CKEditor, CodeIgniter, Mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3, ckeditor4.x

When I am updating content with CKEditor (CodeIgniter) and saving in MySQL, I'm losing some data. The content storing in db is: `'<p [removed] justify;"> some text... </p>'`.
First time there was no [removed] tag in db and all content was there but when I'm updating frequently I'm getting this problem. How can I overcome it?

Comment: What does the content look like before it's getting mangled? Chances are it has an error and gets removed for that reason

Comment: It was like <p> text content... </p>. What type error can be there?

Comment: Can you show the exact code please?

Comment: <!-- CK Editor -->
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
      // Replace the <textarea id="ckeditor"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR({
        toolbar: 'Full',
        enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
    });
});

Comment: No, I mean the exact HTML code that is getting mangled

Comment: 2. View
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <tr>
  <td>Description</td>
  <td>
   <?php echo form_textarea('description', set_value('description', $body->description), "class='textarea form-control ckeditor'"); ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

Comment: 3. Controller
public function edit_body()
{
 $data['description'] = $this->input->post('description', TRUE));
 $insert_id = $this->body_model->save_where($data, array('bodyid' => $this->bodyid));
}

Comment: 4. Model:
public function save_where($data, $where = NULL){
 if ($where != NULL) {
  $this->db->set($data);
  $this->db->where($where);
  $this->db->update($this->table);
  return $this->db->affected_rows();
 }
}
5. 
field (description) type (text) Collation (utf8_unicode_ci)